# Java - byte array from string

Tags: java, arrays, byte, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

For example, I have a string "DEADBEEF". How can I convert it to byte[] bytes = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF } ?

Comment: See [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Comment: Why don't people use the API? :[

Comment: Are you trying to convert the string to hex, or to ASCII bytes?  The ASCII bytes for "DEADBEEF" are not `{ 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF }`.

Comment: He did not say ASCII -- why is everyone assuming he wants ASCII? That is what you get for answering a question within 3 seconds of reading it.

Comment: @Nick is right, take a look at the array he wants produced.

Comment: @alexcoco - then the wording of his question is very misleading

Comment: @Richard I don't disagree with you there. It's not clear at all.

Comment: @alexcoco - given that no-one actually knows what this guy is asking and the OP hasn't clarified, it's pretty harsh for Nick to dv everyone.

Comment: @Richard H - sorry, but it is very clear - he wants to parse a string that contains bytes in hex notation. And it is clearly a duplicate (wjans found the very same question).

Comment: @Richard That's his decision. I haven't voted on any answers whatsoever. None that I saw seem to answer what I think RankoR is asking but the question is not clear so I suppose it's no one's fault that they're technically wrong. I just wanted to point out that most people didn't understand the question. At least, I think they didn't understand. We'll have to wait for an accepted answer to be sure.

Comment: Just fix those answers already -- getBytes() is clearly not the right answer

Comment: To everyone commenting here (other than Nick and wjans): I think from the question (and the example) it is totally clear what RankoR wants - convert a hexadecimal representation to a byte array. **Please read the whole question, not only the title.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop through each pair of two characters and convert each pair individually:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length()/2];

for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2 )
    bytes[i/2] = ((byte)Character.digit(str.charAt(i),16))<<4)+(byte)Character.digit(str.charAt(i),16);
```

I haven't tested this code out (I don't have a compiler with me atm) but I hope I got the idea through. The subtraction/addition simply converts 'A' into the number 10, 'B' into 11, etc. The bitshifting <<4 moves the first hex digit to the correct place.

EDIT: After rethinking it a bit, I'm not sure if you're asking the correct question. Do you want to convert "DE" into {0xDE}, or perhaps into {0x44,0x45} ? The latter is more useful, the former is more like a homework problem type question.

Comment: + 1Yeah -- somebody who got the question!

Comment: Why would the latter be more useful? The first is standard hex encoding. I'm hard pressed to find a problem that fits your "better" interpretation.

Comment: @musiKk: The latter is called "ASCII encoding", not "hexadecimal decoding".

Comment: @tskuzzy: -1. This code is specialized to the input - it works only with the hexadecimal digits `A` to `F`, not with normal `0` to `9` (which also occur in hexadecimal numbers). Better use `Character.digit(c, 16)` instead of your `c - 'A' + 10`.  (Please comment after you fix this, and I will undo my downvote.)

Comment: @musiKk: Oh never mind, you're right. I was thinking more along the lines of an arbitrary String (e.g. "QWERTY") being converted in that fashion (which obviously makes no sense).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: Thanks for that, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

getBytes() would get you the bytes of the characters in the platform encoding. However it sounds like you want to convert a String containing a Hex representation of bytes into the actual represented byte array.

In which case I would point you toward this existing question: [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) (note: I personally prefer the 2nd answer to use commons-codec but more out of philosophical reasons)

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the string to a long and then extract the bytes:

```
String s = "DEADBEEF";
long n = Long.decode( "0x" + s );  //note the use of auto(un)boxing here, for Java 1.4 or below, use Long.decode( "0x" + s ).longValue();
byte[] b = new byte[4];
b[0] = (byte)(n >> 24);
b[1] = (byte)(n >> 16);
b[2] = (byte)(n >> 8);
b[3] = (byte)n;
```

Comment: This works in this case, but in general only for strings up to 16 hex digits (i.e. 8 decoded bytes) long.

Comment: @Paulo that's true, but you could split the string into batches of 16 characters if needed.

Answer (score 1):

tskuzzy's answer might be right (didn't test) but if you can, I'd recommend using [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) from Apache. It has a `Hex` class that does what you need.